# Can't save UUID field in PHP script iteration, Laravel, Postgres

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

I'm trying to fill already existing models with UUID. And every time it says that UUID is not unique! What a bloody hell! )))

```
  function unique_guid($model){
        $guid = com_create_guid();
        $table = $model->table;
        $db_table = Db::table($table);
        $req = $db_table->where("guid", strval($guid));
        $instance = $req->first();

        if(is_object($instance)){
            $guid = unique_guid($model);
            return;
        }else{
            try{
                $model->guid = $guid;
                $model->save();
                sleep(2);
                return $guid;
            }catch(PDOException $Exception){
                $guid = unique_guid($model);
            }

        }
    }
```

It keeps circling in try/catch block and telling me that it is not unique,

**i checked and there is no record with generated UUID**.

Also - it brokes at third-fourth iteration, and if i add sleep(5) it works longer - 10 iteration and then brokes.
What in the world can it be?
Laravel 5.5, Postgres 9

Comment: what is doing `com_create_guid();` function? is that creating `UUID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's some bug in Postgres 9.3. It inserting two rows at a time on some point of the script. I've eneded with just a migration like that

```
 public function up()
    {
        DB::statement('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";');
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE feegleweb_octoshop_products ADD COLUMN guid uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() UNIQUE;');
    }
```

It fill all my rows with unique uuid

Answer (score 3):

Following the [Laravel 6.0 official doc](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#column-modifiers), I proceeded as follows:

I added the **uuid-ossp** extension at database creation. Then, my migrations were like:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression;
...
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('my_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('guid')->primary()->default(new Expression('uuid_generate_v4()'));
        ...
    });
}
```

I find it a lot more elegant like this.

Comment: Working in laravel 10... thx

Answer (score 0):

I believe com_create_guid is not generating unique on every iteration, so please use some increment/prefix value to generated UUID, also if possible use [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) instead of  com_create_guid()  [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) generates id based on the current time in microseconds.

```
function unique_guid($model,$increment=0){
    $guid = uniqid($increment,TRUE);
    $table = $model->table;
    $db_table = Db::table($table);
    $req = $db_table->where("guid", strval($guid));
    $instance = $req->first();

    if(is_object($instance)){
        $guid = unique_guid($model,++$increment);
        return;
    }else{
        try{
            $model->guid = $guid;
            $model->save();
            sleep(2);
            return $guid;
        }catch(PDOException $Exception){
            $guid = unique_guid($model,++$increment);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you created function to generate `UUID` but there is some other better ways to generate `UUID`. You are using `Laravel` so you can search packages which are generating `UUID`.

There is a package I'm suggesting to use.

```
https://github.com/ramsey/uuid
```

These types of packages are useful and fully tested by community. So we can trust on them.

Comment: i checked and there is no record with generated UUID at the moment when it saves, and when i'm moving to next step there is PDO exception about unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.. it will check until the guid is really unique

```
public static function generateUniqueNumber($model = null, $column = null)
{
    $num = null;
    if ($model) {
        $range = $model::all()->pluck('guid')->toArray();
        while (in_array($num = com_create_guid(), $range)) {}
    }

    return $num;
}
```

Comment: Man, i've got 36 000 models in DB)